# Upgrade from TPM 1.2 to 2.0 on a Dell Precision T7610

Tags: tpm, dell-precision

I need to upgrade the TPM firmware on my Dell Precision T7610 from v1.2 to v2.0, however there is no TPM upgrade available on the Dell support website. They have an upgrade utility that covers a wide range of platforms, including the T7510 and T7710, but not the T7610. Is this model just not upgradeable to TPM 2.0? Are there any physical hardware changes that can be done, such as swapping out the TPM chip?

Below are the two error messages I get when trying to run the update utility that was designed for the T7510, et. al.

[image: First error]
[image: Second error]

Comment: The computer has UEFI available. I ran the update utility (Windows 10) both with the original BIOS version (A07), and then again after updating the BIOS to A17 - it exits immediately with an error.

Comment: " it exits immediately with an error." - What error?  Instead of commentary edit your question

Answer (score 1):

I've had a fair bit of experience recently with upgrading TPM chips from 1.2 to 2.0 on Dell laptops, and I'm afraid if there is no firmware upgrade available from Dell, you're out of luck, at least for now. It's possible that Dell might release an upgrade utility for this model in the future, but I think it's unlikely given that they have already done so for other models of a similar age.

The chip is not replaceable without replacing the entire mainboard - we've had a small number of TPM failures and a mainboard replacement was the route Dell went when it came to warranty service. If Dell don't have an upgrade utility available they don't have mainboards with a 2.0 TPM firmware either.

Your question doesn't specify why the upgrade is needed. Depending on your issue there may be another solution, so you may find it worthwhile to create a separate question with more details of the root problem you're looking to solve. If it's BitLocker related, you may well be experiencing the same scenario we did.

Comment: My company's security policy will soon require TPM 2.0 for all their computers - don't ask me why. I've spent a lot of time and money upgrading my T7610 to do modeling and simulation (tons of ram and CPU cores), and now I'm afraid I'll have to ditch it even though it's nowhere near obsolete.

Comment: @Carlton - In addition to the firmware there is also a hardware difference between TPM 1.2 and TPM 2.0.  Sounds like your company will have to replace your device, if it is going to put a blanket policy, of requiring TPM 2.0

Comment: The T7610 is a Sandy Bridge system and I’ve never seen a TPM 2.0 until Broadwell. So I agree with the answer that it’s too old for TPM 2.0. And as @Ramhound says TPM 2.0 involves hardware changes; switchable systems actually have two chips.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with my T7810, I lost TMP 1.2 after I try to upgrade to 2.0.

After I performed the TPM BIOS 2.0 upgrade, I can't see 1.2 or 2.0 either, and got "the system TPM query failed" when I try to downgrade to 1.2

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.